# Celery: Too many open files - how to solve if OS has plenty of descriptors available?

Tags: python, ubuntu, operating-system, celery

I've got a celery app, configured like so in systemd on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Celery Service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=workers.service
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=celery-user
Group=celery-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/celery-user/app
ExecStart=/home/celery-user/app_venv/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --concurrency=300 --soft-time-limit=15000 --loglevel=info --logfile=/var/log/celery/worker.log
KillSignal=SIGTERM

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, whenever I try to start the app with `sudo systemctl start celery.service`, the service starts but in the logs I instantly see this:

```
[2020-03-27 17:44:06,052] CRITICAL worker.start: Unrecoverable error: OSError(24, 'Too many open files')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/celery-user/app_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 205, in start
    --- snip ---
  File "/home/celery-user/app_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/connection.py", line 569, in Pipe
    fd1, fd2 = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

I've seen plenty of others with a similar issue, but nothing suggested so far has worked. I did a standard check of all the usual open files suspects, but nothing looks unusual to me. I bumped several of the maximums up quite high just to check that these were not in fact the issue, as you can see here:

```
$ ulimit -Hn
1000000
$ ulimit -Sn
1000000
$ sysctl fs.file-nr
fs.file-nr = 1536       0       3256496
```

If I reduce the concurrency significantly, to 100, it starts no problem and the 100 child processes all come up and start processing work.

Does anyone have any idea what else could be wrong? As best I can tell, the OS has plenty of headroom for open files.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, systemd does not inherit the user's limits. I launched celery with a low number of workers, then inspected `/proc/<main_celery_pid>/limits` and discovered this:

```
Max open files            1024                4096                files
```

In other words, it was still using the defaults. By adding this to the `[Service]` section of my systemd conf file for celery, all worked as expected:

```
LimitNOFILE=10000
```

Inspecting the processes limit file again after making the edit and restarting:

```
Max open files            10000                10000                files
```